# Changing background color of Ionic ion-item in CSS

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework

I have added the following code `style="background-color: #C2A5A5 !important`.  But that has not worked for me.  how can I add background color to ion-item?Thanks in advance.

```
<ion-item class="item-remove-animate item-avatar item-icon-right" style="background-color: #C2A5A5 !important" ng-repeat="detail in details" type="item-text-wrap" ng-controller="ChatsCtrl"  ng-click="openShareModel(detail)">
    <img ng-src="{{profilepic.profileimageurl}}">

    <h2>{{detail.date | date :'fullDate'}}</h2>
    <h2>{{detail.title}}</h2>
    <p>{{detail.description}}</p>
    <i class="icon ion-chevron-right icon-accessory"></i>

    <ion-option-button class="button-assertive" ng-controller="ChatsCtrl" ng-click="remove(detail.id)">
      Delete
    </ion-option-button>

  </ion-item>
```

Comment: Can you create the demo here? http://play.ionic.io

Comment: http://play.ionic.io/app/2dd13fe979d4

Comment: in above link I deleted "<ion-option-button class="button-assertive" ng-controller="ChatsCtrl" ng-click="remove(detail.id)">
          Delete
        </ion-option-button>" part.after that background color is set.so how I fix this.I want that delete button also.

Comment: Here I added modified one --http://play.ionic.io/app/d3e25c5faa36

Comment: You can change css code `.item .item-content {
  background-color: transparent !important;
}`

Comment: to where should I add this class?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Ionic is injecting an element inside the `<ion-item>` giving the element a structure of:

```
<ion-item>
  <div class="item-content">
  </div>
</ion-item>
```

The Ionic CSS contains a CSS property:

```
.item-content {
  background-color:#ffffff;
}
```

The inline CSS you added is being applied to the element behind the element with the `#ffffff` background, so you can't see your background color.

Apply the background color to the `.item-content` element, as @ariestiyansyah recommended by adding the following CSS to the Ionic CSS file, or create a custom CSS file and include a `<link>` to it in the header, with the following:

```
.item .item-content {
  background-color: transparent !important;
}
```

Here's the [working demo](http://play.ionic.io/app/f6e905d33b7c).

Comment: How would you do this for just one instance of ion-item and not all of them?

Answer (score 38):

I want to share my solution:

I use the custom CSS properties of ionic 4, so if I want to change the background color I can create a new class called ".item-background-color" and change the color of the CSS property that I want to modify. For example:

***my-page.page.scss***

```
.item-background-color{
    --ion-item-background:#015f01d5;
}
```

then, I only add my new class to the ionic item:

***my-page.page.html***

```
<ion-item class="item-background-color">
    My item with new background color
</ion-item>
```

What is done is to change the variable that affects the color of the ionic item, so you can add all the classes you want, dynamically or not, and change the values of their respective variables. You can find information about the variables at [CSS Custom Properties](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/item/#css-custom-properties)

I hope my answer is helpful to people who need to modify the CSS properties of ionic 4 components, sorry for my bad english and good luck!

Comment: This is the best answer for Ionic 5 as well.

Comment: much better solution than the selected answer

Answer (score 14):

Simply, use colors in `variables.scss` file (you can also define new colors) like that

```
$colors: (
 primary:    #f9961e,
 secondary:  #882e2e,
 danger:     #f84e4e,
 light:      #f4f4f4,
 dark:       #222,
 newColor:   #000000,
);
```

and in your html file:

```
 <ion-item color='newColor'>
    Test
 </ion-item>
```

Answer (score 7):

Here's the latest solution:

```js
ion-item {
  --ion-item-background: #ddd;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

**Ionic4 provides color property to give background-color**

e.g.

```
 <ion-item color="light">
 </ion-item>
```

> More theming property available here https://ionicframework.com/docs/theming/basics
>
> Reference doc : https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/item

Comment: Hi do you have any idea about deeplinks in ionic, i m stuck in a issue need some help

Comment: i have migrated to ionic 4 and since then deeplinks have stopped working for me.

Answer (score 4):

Actually got it working in a different way:

```
.item-complex .item-content { background-color: #262B32 !important; }
```

as suggested by @gylippus [here in post #5](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ion-list-background-color/2774/5)

Answer (score 4):

I created a color scheme in variable.scss

```
.ion-color-newcolor {
  --ion-color-base: #224068;
  --ion-color-contrast: #56b4d3;
}
```

Using:

```
<ion-item color="newcolor">
  <ion-label position="stacked">Name: </ion-label>
  <ion-input required type="text"></ion-input>
</ion-item>
```

[image: View:]

Comment: How this is not the correct answer? You share how to properly change the ion-item background color without braking ionic code style

Answer (score 2):

There is a newer solution.

```
<ion-item
    [style.--background]="yourColor"
  >
   //dummy
  </ion-item>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Thanks, that is still working great for Ionic 6. Strangely enough none of the other answers worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

A workaround is using `<a>` tag instead of `<ion-item>` tag, for example: change `<ion-item>` to `<a class="item">` and then style it with whatever you want.

Source: http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#item-icons

Answer (score 0):

In Ionic3, below css will do the trick.

```
.item-ios {
background-color: transparent !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<ion-item>
  <div class="item-content">
  </div>
</ion-item>
The Ionic CSS contains a CSS property:
.item .item-content {
background-color: transparent !important;
}
```

its apply on child dom of `<ion-item>`. We can use can use div `class='item-content'`, but if we won't all the `css(.item-content)` property would apply to the `<ion-item>` child elements like if we use

```
<ion-item>
   Something   //all css will apply into it 
</ion-item>
.item .item-content {
background-color: transparent !important;
}
```

I'm not able to comment that's why I am writing over here.

Answer (score 0):

Now you can use the `appStyleProperty` property of `ion-item` this way:

```
<ion-item
  [appStyleProperty]="{ background: someColor }"
>
</ion-item>
```

Answer (score 0):

You shall use this method. It worked for me.(ion-item needs a inner element to hold the value)

```
<ion-item class="inv_adj_menu"><div>View Details</div></ion-item>
<ion-item class="inv_adj_menu"><div>View Lines</div></ion-item>
<ion-item class="inv_adj_menu"><div>Validate Inventory</div></ion-item>
```