# Setting background to transparent color in an IONIC element

Tags: css, ionic-framework

I am trying to set the background color to 'transparent' for each of the elements in the footer.

```html
<ion-footer>
        <ion-toolbar class="footer">
            <div class="footer-content">
                <ion-item class="footer-item">
                    <ion-icon name="logo-twitter"></ion-icon><a href="https://twitter.com/xxx"> Twitter</a>
                </ion-item>

                <ion-item class="footer-item">
                    <ion-icon --color="blue" name="mail"></ion-icon><a href = "mailto: xxx.com"> Email</a>
                </ion-item>
                <ion-item class="footer-item">
                    <ion-icon name="logo-linkedin"></ion-icon><a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/xxx/"> LinkedIn</a>
                </ion-item>
            </div>
        </ion-toolbar>
    </ion-footer>
```

That's how it looks like at the moment
[image]

I was trying the following setting but it does not work:

```css
 .footer-item{
            margin: auto;
            align-items: center;
            align-content: center;
            font-family: 'Roboto Slab', serif;
            background:  transparent !important;
        }
```

Comment: Do `background-color: transparent` instead.

Comment: @ChrisW., I have tried this too. Does not work

Comment: Which version of Ionic are you using? There's a big difference in how you style ionic components between [version 3](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/theming/theming-your-app/) and [version 4](https://ionicframework.com/docs/theming/advanced) which has switched over to [web components](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Changing background color of Ionic ion-item in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31772742/changing-background-color-of-ionic-ion-item-in-css) - It's usually just a matter of inspecting the element and finding the selector override necessary. The link should describe a correct selector path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is ionic v4 then you should do this `--background: transparent !important;` I hope this helps.